# Get client age in MDX over time period

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to calculate average client age across population. I have an enrollment record per client per month with age dimension key. So, to calculate an average age for one month is not a problem, but when I need to do it for a time period of a year that's where I flounder. How can I write a calculated measure to get age of only the first record per client in the time range?
Thanks everyone for the suggestions.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I would make age a measure with aggregation function "FirstChild". This means that for the time dimension, the first child is taken on each hierarchy level, and for all other dimensions, the age is summed. Hence, this age should be made invisible, and only the average age measure calculated from it by dividing by the number of clients should be made visible.

For this to work properly, you need to set the "Type" property of your time dimension to "Time", and it requires the Enterprise or Development edition of SQL Server. The "FirstChild" aggregation function is not supported in standard edition.